# Chimera- How to go about changing the threshold of the EM map?

Tags: proteins, protein-structure

It is my first time using Chimera. I have uploaded a PDB file on to Chimera and opened it up on the software. I need to change the threshold of the EM map so that I can analyze what the EM map would look like with a threshold too high and too low.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Could you supply more details on the goal of your analysis?

Comment: https://www.cgl.ucsf.edu/chimera/current/docs/ContributedSoftware/volumeviewer/framevolumeviewer.html

Comment: I am trying to view a protein with a threshold that Is too high, a threshold that is too low, and finally, the correct threshold to se the secondary structures.